How can I modify the note and footnote of the template article for Elsevier's document class `elsarticle'
I'm working with the template article for Elsevier's document class `elsarticle'.
This is an MWE:
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the option review to obtain double line spacing
%% \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
%% please give \usepackage{epsfig}

%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}

\journal{Nuclear Physics B}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

%% Title, authors and addresses


\title{Title of Your Manuscript}


\author[inst1]{Author One}

\affiliation[inst1]{organization={Department One},%Department and Organization
            addressline={Address One}, 
            city={City One},
            postcode={00000}, 
            state={State One},
            country={Country One}}

\author[inst2]{Author Two}
\author[inst1,inst2]{Author Three}

\affiliation[inst2]{organization={Department Two},%Department and Organization
            addressline={Address Two}, 
            city={City Two},
            postcode={22222}, 
            state={State Two},
            country={Country Two}}

\begin{abstract}
%% Text of abstract
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{abstract}


\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
keyword one \sep keyword two
%% PACS codes here, in the form: \PACS code \sep code
\PACS 0000 \sep 1111
%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
\MSC 0000 \sep 1111
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%% \linenumbers

%% main text
\section{Sample Section Title}
\label{sec:sample1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.

%% The Appendices part is started with the command \appendix;
%% appendix sections are then done as normal sections
\appendix


 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
 \bibliography{cas-refs}

\end{document}

This yields a note on the first page "Preprint submitted to Nuclear Physics B".
The command \journal{Nuclear Physics B} controls the name of the journal to be generated.

I want to change the note on the first page from "Preprint submitted to Nuclear Physics B" to "Accepted for publication in Nuclear Physics B". I've tried searching for the text "Preprint" in the elsarticle.cls file but couldn't find it.
For your convenience, here's an MWE on Overleaf, feel free to modify it.
Thank you.
